# Databricks: cannot import custom python module

Tags: python, package, databricks, python-wheel

I am trying to create a python package, which then I want to install on my databricks cluster. I have tried different approaches, but they all end up with `ModuleNotFoundError` error. I want to create it out of this `data_aggregation` directory, which is marked as `package`, according to my pycharm. It's nested inside of my project, so I wonder if this could be an issue?

[image]

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='dataaggpackage',
    version='test',
    packages=['data_aggregation'],
    url='',
    license='test',
    author='czept',
    author_email='test',
    description='test'
)
```

However, trying to build a package(py -m build) using it, results in:
[image]

So then, I change my setup file to this, assuming that it would pick up the data_agreggation dir as a root.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='dataaggpackage',
    version='test',
    packages=[''],
    url='',
    license='test',
    author='czept',
    author_email='test',
    description='test'
)
```

It builds correctly, I can install it on databricks cluster, but cannot import it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could anyone help with the solution? I too have this issue

Comment: Still having the same issue with databricks :-(

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is because your setup.py file should be at the root of your project. Since it is in the data_aggregation folder, it can't find it. On your second setup, it builds but you don't have any packages in your setup.py

I would suggest using `setuptools.find_packages()`. It will go through your directory and look for **init.py** files. Your project should be organized like this :

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml  # AND/OR setup.cfg, setup.py
├── ...
└── dataaggpackage/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
    ├── module.py
    ├── subpkg1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── module1.py
    └── subpkg2/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        └── module2.py
```

and your setup.py :

```py
import setuptools
 
setup(
    name='dataaggpackage',
    version='test',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    url='',
    license='test',
    author='czept',
    author_email='test',
    description='test'
)
```

Check out [setuptools official documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html) for reference.